# Interpreting and reporting gamm4 result

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, generalized-additive-model, gamm4

I am new to generalized additive models (GAMs), and most of my knowledge comes from [this document](http://www3.nd.edu/%7Emclark19/learn/GAMS.pdf). Now I am using a generalized additive model with random effects to model some data, where I want to see how "speedChange" correlates with "response" in my dataset, with consideration of random effects "user.id".

The code I run is shown as follows:

```
speed.gammer <- gamm4(response ~ s(speedChange) , data= t, 
                      random= ~ (1|user.id))
```

The GAM can be plotted as follows:

[image: Plot of gam fit with confidence bands]

I then try to interpret the GAM:

```
summary(speed.gammer$gam)
```

which gives the following output:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
response ~ s(speedChange)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.30618    0.01482   155.6   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                 edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(speedChange) 5.875  5.875 28.61  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.0263   
lmer.REML =  14688  Scale est. = 0.57643   n = 5619
```

From what I understand from the output, I learned that speedChange is significantly correlated with response, and the non-linear relationship is as shown in the plot. I know the $R^2$ is small, but that's not what I want to ask. I actually don't understand the `mer` model.

If I run:

```
summary(speed.gammer$mer)
```

I got the following results:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']

REML criterion at convergence: 14687.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.5908 -0.6500 -0.0454  0.5880  3.7110 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name           Variance Std.Dev.
 user.id  (Intercept)     0.2853  0.5342  
 Xr       s(speedChange) 56.4011  7.5101  
 Residual                 0.5764  0.7592  
 Number of obs: 5619, groups:  user.id, 3042; Xr, 8

Fixed effects:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value
X(Intercept)        2.306181   0.014823  155.58
Xs(speedChange)Fx1 -0.008977   0.115045   -0.08

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
X(Int)
Xs(spdCh)F1 0.004
```

I understand this is a `lmerMod`. I understand the output for the `lmer` function, but not here. I don't understand what "X" means in the fixed effects. From the t-value, it seems that the intercept is significant, but not the speedChange. I want to report the result of my analysis, but what is the relationship between the `gam` results and this `mer` result? How can I interpret the `mer` result of:

```
Xs(speedChange)Fx1 -0.008977   0.115045   -0.08
```

Together with the `gam` result:

```
s(speedChange) 5.875  5.875 28.61  <2e-16 ***
```

I don't see any documents that help me to understand the output in order to report the result. Could someone help?